# MySQL throws error after changing encoding

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

I have the following php code

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","admin","***");
mysql_select_db("DbName");
$sql=mysql_query("select * from `menu`");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

This code didn't work after I changed my database's encoding to UTF8-general_ci. What do I have to do in order to work my php code with my new database encoding?

It returns me the message:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
```

Comment: Please *never* describe your problem with "doesn't work". Please always describe *exactly* what happens.

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: and this one Notice: Undefined variable: output in both above

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that your database connection continues to be ISO-8859-1, while `json_encode()` expects UTF-8 data (and breaks if invalid characters are encountered).

Try sending the following query after connecting to the database:

If you're on mySQL < 5.0.7:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8;");
```

if you're on a newer mySQL:

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```