# PHP reading a mysql data encoded in utf8_unicode_ci

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following php code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","*****");
mysql_select_db("MyData");
$sql=mysql_query("select * from menu");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

My data base is encoded on utf8_unicode_ci.
So when I read the output in a browser the latin characters a presented well but greek characters are presented with "???????".When I read the data from my data base are presented regularly.
Can someone help me about what do I have to do with my php code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL throws error after changing encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097364/mysql-throws-error-after-changing-encoding)

Answer (score 8):

add these 2 queries to after `mysql_select_db("MyData");` :

```
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
header('Content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8');
```

You'd need to do this before the `print()` call in your script.

Comment: this is duplicated. you sohuld know with 30k rep

Comment: @yes123, so put the link in the comment! High rep does not a mindreader make.

Answer (score 1):

PHP :

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

HTML :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

File : Convert file to UTF-8 using notepad

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your html encoding, because it is likely to be ISO-LATIN-1 default and thus your display is the issue not the sql.
In that case you want to do the following

`<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

</head>  <?php print(json_encode($output)); ?>

</html>`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in a similar way as MBarsi, adding a line of code after selecting the database, but using mysqli:

```
$mysqli->select_db("database"); 
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```